# Rating place

Tags: mysql, load, innodb, rating

I'm trying to generate rating place table using following receipt

[Assign places in the rating (MySQL, PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776821/assign-places-in-the-rating-mysql-php)

but my database is high loaded.

I tried not to create table, but use MEMORY TABLE and update it using following SQL query

**insert into tops (uid) select uid from users order by exp desc;**

but got the following MySQL error

**Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction**

because there are too many queries until SQL select is being executed.

How to solve this problem?

P.S. **CREATE TABLE tops as SELECT** work almost fine except high server load... up to load average: 50 if tops are non-memory table.

My table users has near 4.5 millions of rows.

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 0):

1. thing to note is that MEMORY tables handle table locking like MYISAM (they both do full table locks) .

4.5 million rows is a lot of inserts to do off of  a select. I think a good approach would be to write a script that pulls down the users table data in chunks and does batch inserts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InnoDB` instead of memory table if you need high concurrency.

`InnoDB` supports **row-level locking** and **MVCC** (Multiversion Concurrency Control) which I think is what you need. `Memory` and `MyISAM` would be faster (when inserting/updating) but if you are experiencing frequent dead-locks then `InnoDB` would be the way to go.

If InnoDB are giving you performance issues during high load most likely it is due to fragmented indexes and too many page splits. You can solve this problem by periodically doing `ALTER TABLE innodb_tbl_name ENGINE=InnoDB` which would rebuild the table and therefore indexes for optimal performance.